# When I shoot from a gun while walking, the bullet is off the center, but when stand still it's fine. (Video Included)

Tags: unity

I am making a small project in Unity, and whenever I walk with the gun and shoot at the same time, the bullets seem to curve and shoot off 2-3 CMs from the center. When I stand still this doesn't happen.

This is my main Javascript code:

```
@script RequireComponent(AudioSource);

var projectile : Rigidbody;
var speed = 500;
var ammo = 30;
var fireRate = 0.1;
private var nextFire = 0.0;

function Update() {
    if(Input.GetButton ("Fire1") && Time.time > nextFire) {
        if(ammo != 0) {
            nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
            var clone = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, transform.root.rotation);
            clone.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3 (0, 0, speed));
            ammo = ammo - 1;
            audio.Play();
        } else {
        
        }
    }
}
```

I assume that these two lines need to be tweaked:

```
var clone = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, transform.root.rotation);
clone.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3 (0, 0, speed));
```

I just started Unity, and I might have a difficult time understanding some things.

**EDIT:**

Here is a video - http://www.screenr.com/2pxH

(If there are any more mistakes in my code, feel free to edit it.)

Comment: When you say the bullet lands "off-center" do you just mean that they don't land exactly under the crosshair? EG If you move left does the bullet land to the right, if you move right does it land to the left?

Comment: When you walk the bullet's movement instead of going to the center of the screen, it shifts or curves so it's a little bit off by like 2-3 cm. I will create a video. Hang tight.

Comment: Could be the bullets are children of the object doing the shooting. That means they're moving along with the parent. Try removing the parent: `transform.parent = null;`

Comment: Added that, but now the spawn point doesn't move with the gun. It just stays on it's original spot, I can walk with my gun and stuff byt the actuall spawn point just stays unattached. I can shoot though. By the way here is a video:

Comment: http://www.screenr.com/2pxH

Comment: It's hard to tell without any point of reference, but it just seems like your bullets are to your right because you are moving left and they don't inherit your velocity.

Try something like 
`clone.velocity = playerVelocity;`
`clone.velocity += transform.TransformDirection(Vector3 (0, 0, speed));`

and see if that creates effects more in line with what you are going for, it will still be off center when accelerating though.

Comment: Actually disregard that, looking again there is a noticeable angle that shouldn't be there. My guess would be something is going wrong with `transform` (because everything else looks fine) so maybe have a look at whatever code creates or modifies that variable.

Comment: __Unknown identifier: 'playerVelocity';__

Comment: That was just pseudocode, replace `playerVelocity` with whatever code you would use to grab the velocity of your player object. I don't think it will actually solve your issue though.

Comment: Just noticed, when going forward the bullets tend to shift downwards, and if I go backwards, the bullets shift upwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to handle bullets in Unity is have them travel instantaneously through [raycasting](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html).

```
var hit : RaycastHit;
if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, hit)){
    var bullet = Instantiate(projectile, hit.collider.transform.position, transform.root.rotation);
}
```

Comment: How exactly do I install it in my code? Sorry, if I am asking too much I just have no clue.

Comment: Replace the two lines you said needed tweaking with it.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that your shooting with the same speed while moving with different speeds.

Imagine you would throw a stone at an angle of 90 degrees to the rails from a moving train. On the train it looks like the stone flies in a straight line from the train, keeping the 90 degrees.

```
 S
 ^
 |
 |
 |
 Train--->
```

An observer standing besides the train sees the stone flying in an angle slightly off the 90 degrees.

```
 O   S
    ^
   |      
  |
 |
 Train--->
```

The speed of the train is added to the speed of the flying stone.

This is not what your code is doing. Your bullet always flies at the same speed in the same direction.

The speed of your bullet when firing needs to be its starting speed plus the speed of the player.

This can be done using vectors:
Calculate the speed vectors of the player and the bullet and add them to get the correct speed.

You already have the bullet speed vector. So you should be able to do something like this:

```
var bullet_speed = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3 (0, 0, speed));
clone.velocity=bullet_speed + player.velocity;
```

This code snippet is not tested, since I don't have Unity.

Comment: I just tried your code, it says unidentified object Player.

Answer (score 0):

the rotation of the projectile might be a little offset from the centre while walking.
Try this

```
var clone = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

Comment: Just tried, and no luck. Same issue is happening.

Comment: something, that just now I noticed in your code; your velocity component is dependant on a value speed which is always 500. irrespective of the current position and rotation values, it will shoot out a bullet at Vector3(0,0,500). Why not use a transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward*magnitude). Play around with different values for the variable magnitude.

Comment: Ehh, like I said I am total noob, could you provide me with a sample code?

Comment: By the way, I tried `transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward*20)` and it makes even a bigger curve now.

Comment: maybe you are not facing forward. try with Vector3.up*20 and Vector3.right*20

Comment: I am going to create a YouTube video, it's very difficult to explain my issue.

Comment: Ok, I have included a video in the post.